# stuck with a calculus problem

Tags: calculus

If: $$y = \dfrac1{1 + x^{n-m}+ x^{p-m}} + \dfrac1{1 + x^{m-n} + x^{p-n}} + \dfrac1{1 + x^{m-p} + x^{n-p}}$$

what is $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ ?

Comment: come on complete your question

Comment: Are you looking for the derivative of y with respect to x?

Comment: yes @JoelReyesNoche

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $x\ne0,$ $$y=\sum_{m,n,p}\dfrac{x^m}{x^m+x^n+x^p}=1$$

Comment: What question are you answering?

Comment: @T.Bongers. $$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=?$$

Comment: you suppose to know the question?

Comment: I see, especially now that OP has edited the question to actually ask a question. It seems that you put more effort into the question than they did.

Comment: i'm sorry to  post incomplete question

Comment: @T.Bongers, Actually the tittle helped me to guess the question